# Odoo 10 - Duplicate supplier info for a given product_template

Tags: odoo-10

I have:

- a) given product_template_id (i.e. id 100)  and
- b) a duplicated product_template_id (i.e. id 200) created using copy() method

copy() method copies only product.template model, so suppliers for that specific product are not copied.

I would like to duplicate all suppliers for that model, but now I am wondering which is the *right* way to do it in Odoo.

If I understood the model properly suppliers prices for a given product are stored in product_supplierinfo table, where each record that points to a given product_tmpl_id specifices a supplier price/qty for a given product_template.

**Which would be the way in Odoo to search for all records that point to a given product_tmpl_id (i.e. 100), duplicate them changing product_tmpl_id to the new one (i.e. 200)?**

Comment: you can do that using odoo import export functionality.

Comment: This is part of a python module, hence I need to do it in programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from the [ORM Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#basic-fields):

> **copy** (`bool`) -- whether the field value should be copied when the record is duplicated (default: `True` for normal fields, **`False` for `One2many` and computed fields**, including property fields and related fields)

The field you're referring to is `seller_ids`, whose field definition is below:

```
seller_ids = fields.One2many('product.supplierinfo', 'product_tmpl_id', 'Vendors')
```

The `copy` attribute is not explicitly defined, so it is `False` by default (as explained in the documentation above). If you want this field to copy along with the other values during the standard product "Duplicate" (`copy` method), you can do this:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    # This only changes the copy attribute of the existing seller_ids field.
    # All other attributes (string, comodel_name, etc.) remain as they are defined in core.
    seller_ids = fields.One2many(copy=True)
```

**Alternatively**

If you want to only have the field copied sometimes, you can extend the `copy` method to look for a specific context value and only copy based on that.

```
# This may take some tweaking, but here's the general idea
@api.multi
def copy(self, vals):
    new_product = super(YourClass, self).copy(vals)
    if vals.get('copy_sellers'):
        new_product.seller_ids = self.seller_ids.copy({'product_id': new_product.id})
    return new_product

# Whatever you have calling the copy method will need to include copy_sellers in vals
vals.update({'copy_sellers': True})
product.copy(vals)
```

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of this option. Still would like to understand how would you do it without modifying the normal behaviour. I am developing a module which at a certain point duplicates products. My concern is how to do it following how things are implemented as per Odoo ORM/API/framework.

Comment: @M.E. This would work in such a way that it happens during the normal duplication process (the `copy` method). If you want to do it explicitly in the `copy` method, I can update my answer with an alternate solution.

Comment: Thanks, will this `new_product.seller_ids = self.seller_ids` make both products refer to same seller_ids or will a new set of seller_ids be generated for this product? Or, if I change later the price/minqty for new_product, would it affect the old product too because seller_ids are actually the same records shared by both products?

Comment: @M.E. Good catch. In that case, These would refer to the same `seller_ids`. I'll update again with how to make sure they are copied (and not unintentionally linked).

Comment: Thanks, my point is that I do not fully understand how the copy shall be executed inside an `api.multi` method. `seller_ids` refers or may refer to many records and hence I am not sure if I have to iterate and copy each one separetely or there is something in the API to do that at once because we are inside an `api.multi` method.

Comment: @M.E. You can see the original definition of `copy` in `models.py`. It is designed to return a single record. It seems that most (but not all) examples  in core are using `@api.one` instead of `@api.multi` to accomodate that.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understood you correctly that single record definition for copy forces to iterate through all seller_ids, right?

Comment: @M.E. Sorry, I think I misunderstood which part you were talking about. I believe the `self.seller_ids.copy` method will only work on one record (you can test this on your own, though). In that case, you may need to loop through the `seller_ids` and copy each one individually.

Comment: Thanks, that was I was looking for.